# How to get instagram profile URL from graph api

Tags: android, instagram

**What I have done**:

1. I have Facebook SDK integrated into my test app
2. I have installed Instagram on the device

**I have the code here that I found in documentation:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-oembed?locale=es_LA

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/instagram_oembed",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

***What is the way to get the profile link of the Instagram account from device***